# SQL get the highest value and concatenate

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

if I have the following table of data

```
ProductID,StockOnSite,StockOffsite
    1           83          81      
    1           98          85      
    1           112         101     
    2           81          85      
    2           115         83      
    2           115         101
```

What I need to do  is get the Highest StockOnSite per ProductID( calculating the StockDifference ) record and concatinate StockOnSite with StockOffsite to create a column StockInfo

output needed

```
ProductID,StockOnSite,StockOffsite,StockDifference,StockInfo
    1           98          85          13          98/85
    2           115         83          32          115/83
```

SQL I have come up with

```
select  ProductID
        ,StockOnSite
        ,StockOffsite
        ,StockDifference = max(StockOnSite - StockOffsite)
from Product
group by ProductID, StockOnSite, StockOffsite
```

I don't know where to go from here ?

Thanks

Below is query to build table and data:

```
CREATE TABLE Products
(
    ProductID int NOT NULL,
    StockOnSite int NOT NULL,
    StockOffsite int NOT NULL
)

insert into table Products(ProductID, StockOnSite, StockOffsite) values(1,83,81)
insert into table Products(ProductID, StockOnSite, StockOffsite) values(1,98,85)
insert into table Products(ProductID, StockOnSite, StockOffsite) values(1,112,101)
insert into table Products(ProductID, StockOnSite, StockOffsite) values(2,81,85)
insert into table Products(ProductID, StockOnSite, StockOffsite) values(2,115,83)
insert into table Products(ProductID, StockOnSite, StockOffsite) values(2,115,101)
```

Comment: Why did you pick 98 for product 1, when there's also 115? Is it because you are looking for the highest difference?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: The difference for ProductID 1 is 98-85 = 13

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select  ProductID
        ,StockOnSite
        ,StockOffsite
        ,StockOnSite - StockOffsite
        ,cast(Stockonsite as varchar(10))+'/' +cast(StockOffsite as varchar(10)) 
from    Products pr1
where   StockOnSite - StockOffsite = (Select max(StockOnSite - StockOffsite)
                                        from Products pr2
                                        where   pr1.ProductID = pr2.ProductID
                                        )
group by ProductID, StockOnSite, StockOffsite
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick.
The query needs to track the product so as not to get confused if the same stock difference occurs in more than 1 product:

```
select p.ProductID
       ,p.StockOnSite
       ,p.StockOffsite
       ,(p.StockOnSite - p.StockOffsite) StockDifference
       ,concat(p.StockOnSite,'/',p.StockOffsite) StockInfo
from   Products p
where  concat(ProductID,'-',(StockOnSite - StockOffsite)) = 
       (
         select concat(ProductID,'-',max((StockOnSite - StockOffsite)))
         from   Products p2
         where  p2.ProductID = p.ProductID
         group  by ProductID
        )
;
```