# SQL Highest Value With Group

Tags: sql, sql-server

What I need to do is get the Highest `StockOnSite` per `ProductID` ( calculating the StockDifference ) record and concatenate StockOnSite with StockOffsite to create a column AllStock

I am completely lost? as I cannot group as we have a StockOnSite and StockOffsite

Here is the SQLFiddle

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/76e50/1)

This is not a duplicate post, as the outer select complicates the grouping.

Thanks

Comment: Can you share the output you're trying to get for this sample data?

Comment: Duplicate...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26421429/sql-get-the-highest-value-and-concatenate/26421720#26421720

Comment: Hi arunbabu, it is not a duplicate question as the outer join now complicates your origianl answer.  Thank you for your time and I did vote you up

Comment: Hi Mureinik, i have a link to a Fiddle you can try

Comment: Thanks.please get back the comments of any answers if it is not satisfy the needs, so that it will help to improve and try for better answer. if you vote up i thought it was useful.

Comment: Can no one solve this SQL problem?

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: I'm lost at the concatenation part. Would you like to get highest stockOnSite per productID and a third column: AllStock that has the SUM value of StockOnSite and StockOffsite? In fact your sentence is really confusing.

Comment: Hi ConsiderMe4 I would like to have the an extra column created which would be the StockOnSite and StockOffsite combined but separated with a '/', so 130/176.  But the main problem I have with this query is getting the highest Stock value whether it be StockOnSite or StockOffsite and returning just 1 record per SiteID

Comment: My expected output would be as SQLFiddle currently but only 1 SiteID per group.  If you look at SQLFiddle we have 3 records for SiteID 1 and 2.We want to keep the record where the StockDiff is greatest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is the query you've been looking for.

It evaluates `StockDiff` as you suggested: `StockOnSite - StockOffSite` and then takes the highest value for every `SiteID`

```
SELECT
  SiteID, Description, StockOnSite, StockOffsite, AllStock, LastStockUpdateDateTime, StockDiff
FROM (
  SELECT 
    *,
    rank() OVER (PARTITION BY SiteID ORDER BY StockDiff DESC) AS rank
  FROM (
      SELECT
        s.SiteID,
        s.Description, 
        p.StockOnSite, 
        p.StockOffsite, 
        CAST(p.StockOnSite AS varchar(10)) + '/' + CAST(p.StockOffSite AS varchar(10)) AS AllStock,
        p.LastStockUpdateDateTime,
        p.StockOnSite - p.StockOffSite AS StockDiff
      FROM 
        Sites s 
        JOIN Products p ON s.SiteID = p.OnSiteID
      ) foo
    ) goo
WHERE rank = 1
ORDER BY 1
```

I used a [Window function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx) to get it done.

**Edit**

If you need highest `StockOnSite` you can easily modify the Window Function by replacing `StockDiff` in `ORDER BY StockDiff DESC` with `StockOnSite`

Answer (score 0):

You wanted to highest StockOnSite by ProductID, but the sample set all had unique productIDs.  This query will get what you're asking for, but I think your question might be unclear as to what your result set needs to look like.

```
select  pr.ProductID
, s.SiteID
 ,s.Description
 ,StockOnSite
 ,StockOffsite
 ,AllStock = cast(coalesce(pr.StockOnSite,'') as varchar(10)) + '-' + cast(coalesce(pr.StockOffsite,'') as varchar(10)) 
 ,LastStockUpdateDateTime = pr.LastStockUpdateDateTime
 ,Stockdiff = StockOnSite - StockOffsite
from Products pr
inner join (
  select    pr.ProductID
  , MAX(StockOnSite) MaxStockOnSite
  from dbo.Products pr
  group by [ProductID]
) x
ON x.ProductID = pr.ProductID
and x.MaxStockOnSite = pr.StockOnSite
inner join dbo.Sites s
ON pr.OnSiteId = s.SiteId
```

Comment: Hi Vinnie,  Thanks for the effort not quite right as I wanted highest StockOnSite by SiteID. Can you help?

Answer (score 0):

this query may help you :

```
select * from Products p1
join
(
  select onsiteid,max(stockonsite-stockoffsite) as stockdiff
  from products
  group by onsiteid
) p2
on p1.onsiteid = p2.onsiteid and (p1.stockonsite - p1.stockoffsite) = p2.stockdiff
```

you can modify select as per your need.